# Can list initialization not be used for private members?

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization

```
struct A
{
private:
    int a, b, c;
};

int main()
{
    A a1{};
    A a2 = {};

    return 0;
}
```

The code was compiled by VC++ 2012 (with the latest update "Nov 2012 CTP").

I expect a1 and a2 are zero-initialized, but not. a1 and a2 are not initialized.

Why?

Comment: What does this list initialization have to do with your private members?!

Comment: @Tom, if data members are public, then the result will be as expected.

Comment: @TomWijsman: Here's a giant life hint: "common sense" means "I think it should be true but I have no backing facts for my statement". I'm not saying you're wrong. I'm saying if you're right, you've given no reason for anyone to believe you are. The language isn't defined from "common sense", it's defined by a standard. Yeah, you can get an initial idea with "common sense", but when it comes to answering the question it would be nice to rely on something more concrete.

Comment: @xmllmx: This in not about prohibiting, it is about implementation. The standard expresses nowhere that private children are to be initialized, you can easily find the opposite as shown by Xeo; because why would you be able to initialize **private** members from the outside? You tell me that.

Comment: @GManNickG: I'm not here for answering, subtle difference. I'm looking for an answer to my comment... ;)

Comment: @xmllmx: The accepted answer is **wrong**, while the answer by Nicol Bolas is **correct**. Reconsider your acceptance.

Comment: @TomWijsman: Xeo is incorrect in his answer, the standard does determine that those members must be initialized to 0. Xeo has skipped a join in the chain of quotes and has incorrectly considered *value-initialization* as a call to the constructor (which it will be only if there is a user provide default constructor).

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Okay, thanks for keeping me up to date and answering my first comment. But to be skeptic, why did he say `Clang and GCC agree too` then? Are they at fault too? Because then we should file a bug against them too.

Comment: @Tom: I made the mistake to only test against relatively old versions (GCC 4.5.1 and Clang 3.1 (although that one is the current release, 3.2 trunk seems to have fixed it)).

Comment: @TomWijsman: Compliance or lack of compliance with the standard does not make it more/less correct in standard terms. I can provide some clauses in C++03 that no compiler **ever** complied with. Agreement among compilers does not define a standard.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: I'm not implying that, I'm just saying such bugs should be reported. What's the use of a standard if no compiler does what the standard say? :)

Comment: @TomWijsman: So much for that "common sense", huh?

Comment: @GManNickG: Not sure what you are talking about, I was looking for an answer to my comment. I'm on the "questioning" side, please take your obsolete comments elsewhere.

Comment: @TomWijsman: I'm talking about your conveniently deleted comments about this not being a bug because it's "common sense" that the private members are private. Don't worry about it.

Comment: @GManNickG: I don't see your point, I'm "questioning"; else I would've posted an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You mean Microsoft's Community Tech Preview compiler, which they aren't even confident enough in to call it a *beta*, has *bugs* in it? ;)

This is a bug; it should behave as you expect. Please report it as such.

Comment: Are you sure? The members are `private` and that means that the type is not an aggregate, which in turn means that the syntax represents a call to the implicitly declared default constructor. The implicitly defined default constructor does not initialize POD members, which means that `a`,`b`,`c` should not be initialized. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually disregard my last comment, **this answer is correct**. The syntax in the question is *list-initialization* which in this case maps to *value-initialization* and that in turn means *zero-initialization* in this particular case. +1

Answer (score 6):

<sup>Note that this answer had a slight rewrite that changed the end result to the opposite of what it was before. Thanks to @[David Rodríguez - dribeas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36565/david-rodriguez-dribeas) for enlightening me. :)</sup>

**This is a bug.** Clang 3.2 trunk and GCC 4.7+ agree too and will zero-initialize the members.

Time for some standardese. Note that `T x{};` (or `= {}`) can be interpreted as either list-initialization *or* aggregate initialization. `A` here is not an *aggregate* because it has private members, and as such can not be initialized by the latter.

`§8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr] p1`

> An *aggregate* is an array or a class (Clause 9) with [...] no private or protected non-static data members [...]

This only leaves list-initialization and that will value-initialize both `a1` and `a2`.

`§8.5.1 [dcl.init.list] p3`

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type `T` is defined as follows:
>
> - If the initializer list has no elements and `T` is a class type with a default constructor, the object is value-initialized.

Value-initialization is specified as follows for our specific case:

`§8.5 [dcl.init] p7`

> if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized [...]

And this in turn means that the members should be zeroed out.

Comment: @Xeo - "call the default ctor if it's non-trivial" : I presume by a non-trivial default ctor is meant a user-defined constructor, rather then a compiler generated default constructor(which wouldn't be called in this case).

Comment: @damienh: No, even a compiler-generated default ctor can be non-trivial if the members or bases have non-trivial ctors (and so on, ultimately leading to a user-defined ctor somewhere in the chain).

Comment: @David: So, rewrote the answer a bit to incorporate my enlightenment. :)

Comment: @damienh: Yes, and that is precisely the reason. If there is no user defined constructor, *zero-initialization* will take care of the POD submembers of the object and the *implicitly defined default constructor* will take care of the members that have user defined constructors. You need both. --Xeo, I don't think you should **nuke** the answer, it has valid data that adds value. You just need to correct the  last part (I will upvote, drop me a comment and I will clear all comments that no longer apply :)